# How can I see the posts that someone liked?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to see all the likes of a Facebook friend — he/she did like some of my posts but I don't remember which ones.

How to see all likes of a friend on my posts/comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posts: Type in: posts [name] likes in the search bar

For pictures: Type photos [name] likes in the search bar

[image: Posts friends like]

[image: Photos friends like]

Comment: You should show the result also.

Comment: This is so so hidden from facebook. Thanks a ton!

Comment: it does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

They may have set security to prevent people seeing their Likes, but...

1. Go to the person's Facebook profile
2. Next to the person's name, pull down the menu (it probably says "About")
3. Click "Likes"

Comment: This is about music, video he/she chooses to show on his profile only. Not the posts I'm seeking

Answer (score 0):

You have to type:

Photos liked by... (name)
Posts liked by... (name)

But it only works a view times. That's because the browser detected it as suspicious activity.

What you do then is install a different browser that you find in your playstore and try it again.

(as example you can try puffin browser or firefox)